# How to process real-time image segmentation using a headless remote-server for processing and the laptop webcam for image capturing

Tags: python, image, server, webcam

I use VSCode to access a headless remote server with GPU for coding and processing. I wish to use the webcam on my laptop that I am using to access the server for real-time image capturing.

How should I code that matches the two up?

E.g., If I were to get the processing done on my laptop, I would have simply mentioned

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

But here it would mean that the camera should be of the remote-server, which doesn't have a camera. It should require a location of my laptop and its default camera.

What to do?

Comment: I guess you'd have to run `gstreamer` or `ffmpeg` on the machine your camera is attached to stream the video onward to the remote machine.